# Why would printf() crash if I pass only one argument, which is a variable?

Tags: c, string, printf

I tried out this program on my machine. Out of ten times, it didn't crash at all, whereas I've been told it might sometimes. What is the reason it's dangerous?

```
char *s = "Hello";
printf("%s",s); // Does not crash
printf(s); // Crashes sometimes?
```

I've thought of two things: "Read-only string", or "Since format string is not given, printf does not identify the parameter as a string", but I'm not sure these are right.

Comment: As it stands it will not crash. One assumes that if s contained formatting parameters it will crash

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks! Can you please give me an example

Comment: The string `%?` Is included, to require an argument Because not passed in practice.

Comment: `char *s="%s %d";" should do the trick

Comment: @EdHeal: `int x = 0; int y = 1/x;` should also do the trick. The code in the question is safe. Some different code may be unsafe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example you give shouldn't crash, because `"Hello"` contains no format specifiers that would cause `printf` to go looking for arguments to format.

But if `s` was a format string, e.g.

```
char *s = "Hello %s!";
printf(s);
```

then you'd have an issue, because there would be no arguments to format into the string.  Note, it doesn't necessarily *crash* outright, but can have unxepected behavior.  e.g. I see

```
Hello h??V?!
```

(plus warnings when trying to compile it!)

Additionally, see [godel9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21068199/722332)—`s` could be reassigned to point to another string.

Answer (score 4):

I think that part of the trick to this question is the fact that `s` is not declared as a `const` pointer.

Since `s` is not declared as a `const` pointer, there's no guarantee that it will always point to the string literal `"Hello"`. For example, the following code results in undefined behavior:

```
const char *s = "Hello"; // i.e. not const char * const s = "Hello";
s = "Hello %s";
printf(s);
```

Comment: Thanks @godel9. Appreciate your help

Comment: @haccks: But not equivalent to `char * const s = "Hello"`, which is what matters here.

Answer (score 2):

Given the code you've shown, there is no reason for either `printf` call to crash. The string literal is effectively read-only, but that's not a problem since `printf` won't attempt to modify it.

`"hello"` is perfectly valid either as a format string or as a second argument with the first argument being the format string `"%s"`.

There is a potential problem if that's the *last* thing the program writes to `stdout`; it's implementation-defined whether a newline `'\n'` is required as the last character written. But it doesn't have to be written as part of the same `printf` call.

If `s` pointed to a string containing something other than `"hello"`, the behavior could be undefined. For example, if `s` happens to point to the string `"%d"` or `'%s"`, and you don't provide a corresponding argument, the behavior is undefined (and the program *could* crash).

It's generally dangerous to pass a pointer to an arbitrary string as the first argument to `printf`, exactly because of the danger of stray `%` characters. But `"hello"` is not an arbitrary string; it's just `"hello"`.

And since `s` is not declared `const`, it could be modified before being passed to `printf` (but that's not possible if the lines you've shown are actually consecutive).

One more thing: since `s` is initialized to point to a string literal, it *should* be declared as:

```
const char *s = "hello";
```

Omitting the `const` means that the compiler won't warn you about attempts to modify the string literal. But since the code you've shown doesn't do that, it's not really an issue.

Bottom line: The code you've shown is perfectly safe, but it's "brittle" in the sense that it could easily blow up in your face if you modify it carelessly. There are things you can do to make it more robust in the presence of future code modifications.

Comment: Thanks much @Keith. Wonderful explanation

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case the program is not supposed to crash.

If, however, you had `char *s = "xx %d yy"` for example, then `printf(s)` would have likely crashed due to a memory access violation, while trying to read an integer value from the stack (because of the `%d` within the input string).

Answer (score 2):

If the string contains a `%` then it will crash. Because the `%` sign and the following character will be interpreted as a conversion character e.g., `%d, %f`. However since this is part of a string, the compiler will not check whether it is valid syntax  -- so you could have `%k` for example and there won't be any value being passed to it. So it will crash.

Try

> "Hello"

, `"Hel%lo"` or `"Hel%lo"`

PS: I can't add a comment, hence I am answering here.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
printf(s);
```

will not crash in your given example.
But printing a string without conversion specifier is **risky when `s` contains the `%` character**. In that case you wouldn't get the desired result, since `printf` will assume it is the beginning of a *conversion specification*.